# Problem in Group By

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem in group by in Magento 1.9 , I have tested all the query , it works except the last line

```
SELECT DISTINCT catalog_product_entity_text.value   AS nomproduit,
            sales_flat_order.created_at         AS datedecommande,
            sales_flat_order.subtotal           AS prixavantremise,
            sales_flat_order.grand_total        AS prixapresremise,
            sales_flat_order_address.firstname  AS prenom,
            sales_flat_order_address.lastname   As nom,
            sales_flat_order_address.telephone  AS telephone,
            sales_flat_order_address.country_id AS pays
FROM catalog_product_entity t,
 sales_flat_order,
 sales_flat_order_address,
 catalog_product_entity_text
     LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order AS sales
               ON (sales.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_text.entity_id)
     LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS address
               ON (address.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_text.entity_id)
     LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity as sku
               on (sku.entity_id = sales.entity_id)
where sales_flat_order.coupon_code like 'xxxxx';/*
group by  t.sku,sales_flat_order.entity_id;*/
```

Can anyone help me , I got stuck at this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share full query.? the above query is being incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this SQL statement doesnt make any sense at the moment. I am not even sure what you want to do here.
Actually you have comparings of at whole different values there like

```
on (sku.entity_id = sales.entity_id)
```

the entity_id out of the catalog_product_entity table has nothing to do with the entity_id of the sales_flat_order table.

If you explain what you want to achieve with this SQL statement, i may can help you.

*edit:

```
SELECT distinct
product.sku   AS nomproduit,
sales.created_at         AS datedecommande,
sales.subtotal           AS prixavantremise,
sales.grand_total        AS prixapresremise,
sales_address.firstname  AS prenom,
sales_address.lastname   As nom,
sales_address.telephone  AS telephone,
sales_address.country_id AS pays
FROM
sales_flat_order_item as sales_item
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity as product ON product.entity_id=sales_item.product_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order as sales ON sales.entity_id=sales_item.order_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address as sales_address ON sales_address.parent_id=sales.entity_id AND address_type='billing'
WHERE sales.coupon_code = 'zpa2012'
group by product.sku, sales.entity_id
```

maybe this is what you want ?

Comment: I want to get orders by their promocode and filtered by sku in order to show : orderdate,pricebefore reduction, telephone ..